# Do i need to clear Greed Cave to Marry Mist?

Tags: rune-factory

In [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/930701-rune-factory-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/51707) it says to marry mist my requirements are

- Complete the storyline.
- Till ALL the soil in your farmland.

while [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/930701-rune-factory-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/47243) say that i just need to get the licences to Greed Cave

So do i need to clear Greed Cave in order to marry Mist, or is just being able to get into it more than enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't. the first guide linked is in fact wrong in terms of the "Complete the story line" Requirement. You only need to have gained the licences to access Greed Cave (and tilled all farmland soil) in order to purpose to Mist.

before facing the final boss i cleared my entire farmland and tilled it ready to purpose to her at any time (given i was level 99 with +200 ATK and DEF so the Final Boss was no real threat) and checked to see if she would say yes before i even went into Greed Cave.

Also, i should mention that the marriage scene wont be any different regardless if you complete the game or not

> as even after beating the game, despite the entire town giving you there congratulations for your's and Mist's marriage Lynette does not come